# Doubled title suffix in admin (backend) pages - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, bug, meta-title, magento-1.9.4

A client needs to add Title Suffix to show in all Magento administration pages. So I added it in `System -> Configuration -> General -> Design -> Title Suffix` and when I enter some text, this text shows twice. 
For example, if I enter `| My page`, it shows:

`Configuration / System / Magento Admin | My page | My page`.

Is this Magento bug?